# Protocol and Delegation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a protocol and a delegate in Swift but i'm having some issues. I want to have a switch button in the cells of a Table View. Here is my protocol:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol CellProtocol {
    func onSwitchToogle (sender : AnyObject , onCell : UITableViewCell)
}
```

Here is my cell class:

```
import UIKit

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var flag: UISwitch!
    var cellDelegate:CellProtocol!

    @IBAction func Toogle(sender: AnyObject) {
        if((cellDelegate?.onSwitchToogle(sender, onCell: self)) != nil){

        }
    }
}
```

And here is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CellProtocol {    
    func onSwitchToogle(sender: AnyObject, onCell: UITableViewCell) {

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell 
        cell.label.text = "sadsad"
        return cell
    }
}
```

The problem is: it never enters in the if condition in the IBAction of my switch and it never enters in the method on the ViewController.

Comment: Plus... `onSwitchToogle()` doesn't return anything, so I'm not even sure what you're trying to do with that `if` statement...

Comment: Don't make your delegate implicitly unwrapped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You want to make sure that you specify the delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell 
       cell.cellDelegate = self
       cell.label.text = "sadsad"
       return cell
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you don't have a strong reference cycle by making the `cellDelegate` property `weak`:

   ```
   weak var cellDelegate: CellProtocol!
   ```
3. To allow you to have weak references to the protocol type, you must make the protocol a `class` protocol:

   ```
   protocol CellProtocol : class {
       func onSwitchToggle (sender : AnyObject, onCell : UITableViewCell)
   }
   ```
4. You obviously just want to call `onSwitchToggle` if the delegate is set (using optional chaining):

   ```
   @IBAction func toggle(sender: AnyObject) {
       cellDelegate?.onSwitchToggle(sender, onCell: self)
   }
   ```

   No test is required to make sure the delegate implemented the method, because if the view controller conforms to the protocol, it must implement that method.

Please forgive me, but I changed a method names (toggle vs toogle, start methods names with lowercase letters, etc.), but hopefully this illustrates the key points.

Comment: I wold declare the delegate as an optional, instead of an implicitly unwrapped optional: `weak var cellDelegate: CellProtocol?`

Comment: That depends upon the OP's intent. If the app is designed such that some cells have delegates and others don't, then I agree, it should be optional. If _all_ members of the `Cell` class will _always_ have a `cellDelegate`, then I personally prefer implicitly unwrapped, to make this intent clear.

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath set up the delegate to self:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell

        cell.label.text = "sadsad"
        cell.cellDelegate = self

        return cell

    }
```